# Example of Irreflexive relation in Asymptotic notation

Tags: algorithm

Give an example case for which all the three conditions

f(n)!= O(g(n)),

f(n)!= Theta (g(n)) and

f(n)!= Omega (g(n))

holds true.

---

We can say oscillating representation , i.e. sinx or cos x can hold true for this question. But will it be irreflexive relation? and It is not a non-negative function too. So, what other example is possible for it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not possible. There is not any oscillating function as the period of such function is constant, and you can't get the specified result! Also, if `f(n) !=O(g(n))`, definitely `f(n) = Omega(n)` (might be `Theta(n)`) by the definition. 
I mean if `f(n) != O(g(n))`, then `lim_{n \to infty} g(n)/f(n) = c < \infty`. So, it means `f(n) = Omega(g(n))`  (and if `c > 0`, `f(n) = Theta(g(n)`).

Comment: In the question, I mean all three notation(not any one notation) should not be present in the same function at the same time.

Comment: @Srestha Your answer is no. there is not such a pair function, unfortunately.

Comment: So, reflexivity property not satisfied such a function not exists??

Comment: can chk this  discussion :https://gateoverflow.in/313742/asymptotic_notations-self_doubt

Comment: @Srestha apparently, nobody can't suggest such this function, because it is not possible as I've mentioned.